# Estimote iOS SDK error : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I am able to load up the ios sdk and have the app load on the phone. However, once I click into 1 of the 3 options of the example app, the app crashes with the error :

```
[CLLocationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Given there isn't much of an error and I'm new to mobile applications, I'm not sure where to continue looking for an answer on how to solve this.

Platforms:
XCode 5.0.1
iPhone 5 software version 6.1.3

Comment: Did you look at the docs for the `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:` method? It was added in iOS 7.0. You can't call it on a device running iOS 6 or earlier.

Comment: The error means that you attempted to execute the method startRangingBeaconsInRegion on an object of the class CLLocationManager, and that class does not support that method.  Most likely you put the wrong object in a pointer.  If you set things up properly you'll also be pointed to the exact line where this error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

As this method was added in iOS7, if you attempt to perform this method on a device that is not running iOS7, this crash will occur.

You can ensure that the device can actually perform this method without crashing using the 'respondsToSelector' method, which will check that you can actually call said method.